# Spring/Camel Garbage Collection with Dependency Injections

Tags: spring, memory-management, dependency-injection, garbage-collection

I have configured a Spring app (using Camel for integration with an ActiveMQ broker) such that two particular classes, say, `Person` and `Personality`, get wired-up and injected with all of their dependencies automatically through the Spring container. For the sake of this example, `Person` objects *have* `Personality` objects as members/properties.  So the Spring config file wires up `Personality` instance, and those beans are referenced in the wired `People` beans:

```
<bean id="personality" class="com.me.someProgram.Personality" singleton="false">
    <!-- blah... -->
</bean>

<bean id="person" class="com.me.someProgram.Person" singleton="false">
    <!-- People have Personalities -->
    <property name="personality" ref="personality"/>
    <!-- blah... -->
</bean>
```

Both beans are specified as *prototypes* in scope because this makes sense for my application.  Basically, I need to grab a new instance of `Personality` every time I get a new `Person`.

**My question:**

This is my first application using Spring, and IoC/dependency injection in general.  I am worried about garbage collection and memory leaks. When beans are prototypes, and you have prototypes nested inside of prototypes (via *has-a* relationship), do you have to worry about GC/memory leaks? Or does the Spring container alleviate all of those concerns for you? Are there best practices with regards to Spring/IoC memory management? Any anti-patterns to steer clear of?

My actual business objects are quite large, and I will produce many of them, so if I start heading down a road that is riddled with bad memory management, it's going to be a very, very bumpy ride.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no issues with garbage collection in the above code that are caused by spring.  You can think of the spring config above as another way of saying,

```
Personality personality = new Personality();
Person person = new Person();
person.setPersonality(person);
```

Spring does not maintain a reference to prototype beans it creates, so spring itself will not cause a memory leak.

Spring does maintain references to singleton scoped beans, and those will not be gc'd until the containing application context is.